# Is there way to sort *.md files according to publish date value with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a blog and I am saving these blog posts with markdown file format. The file contains the release date and the update date. I can call the information I need, for example, the release date with the help of the `lowdown` tool. So far everything is going fine. but I couldn't find a way to do this when I want to sort by publish date for my index page.

> **Note**: The date format i am using; `YYYY-MM-DD`

As an example of the result I am trying to reach;

(assuming we're looping through the directory containing the blog posts)

```sh
for post in *.md; do
    title=$(lowdown -X title $post)
    date=$(lowdown -X date $post)
    <h1>$date</h1>
    <h1>$title</h1>
done
```

The output gives natural order(i think).

```
2021-10-02 2th Post
2021-10-04 Last Post
...
```

My expectation is sort them with $date values.

```
2021-10-04  Last Post
2021-10-03  3th Post
2020-10-02  2th Post
2019-10-01  1th Post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe the output through `sort -r` to the get newest post at the top, like this:

```
for post in *.md; do
    title=$(lowdown -X title $post)
    date=$(lowdown -X date $post)
    echo "$date $title"
done | sort -r
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct an array of `YY-MM-DD:filename.md` entries and sort it, to get a list of the file names in their correct order.

```bash
posts=($( for post in *.md ; do
              date=$(lowdown -X date "$post") ;
              echo "$date:$post" ;
          done | sort -rg ))
```

Then, do an actual loop over the entries extracting the content of those files in their correct order:

```bash
separator=""
for post in "${posts[@]}" ; do
    file="${post#*:}"
    date="${post%%:*}"
    title="$(lowdown -X title "$file")"

    printf '%s<h1>%s (%s)</h1>\n' "$separator" "$title" "$date"
    lowdown "$file"

    separator="<hr>"
done
```

Comment: this is also works and it will help me a lot in future. i am grateful